# What are "build-essential" & "build-dep"?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, packages

I am researching how to install Ruby 1.9.1 in Xubuntu 10.04 and I came across the command **build-essential** and **build-dep** multiple times. Sometimes it is followed by packages and sometimes it is both preceded and post-ceded by packages.

The 2 examples I am looking at are:

> sudo apt-get install build-essential
>   zlib1g zlib1g-dev zlibc libruby1.9
>   libxml2 libxml2-dev libxslt-dev
>
> sudo apt-get build-dep ruby1.9

and

> sudo apt-get install ruby irb ri rdoc
>   ruby1.8-dev libzlib-ruby libyaml-ruby
>   libreadline-ruby libncurses-ruby
>   libcurses-ruby libruby libruby-extras
>   libfcgi-ruby1.8 build-essential
>   libopenssl-ruby libdbm-ruby
>   libdbi-ruby libdbd-sqlite3-ruby
>   sqlite3 libsqlite3-dev libsqlite3-ruby
>   libxml-ruby libxml2-dev

Comment: Note that it's not a command, but a package in the Debian package system (APT). You could also acquire the package using GUI tools.

Comment: Thanks. How does it relate to Ruby though? I assume Ruby needs it to run but maybe I am wrong.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

The `build-essential` package is a reference for all the packages needed to compile a Debian package. It generally includes the GCC/g++ compilers and libraries and some other utilities.

[Check out the documentation here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/build-essential).

Comment: Ok but that still does not answer my question fully.  I understand that 'build-essential' contains an informational list of packages which are essential for creating Debian packages. But what is considered a Debian package? Ruby? gcc/g++ compilers? And how does Debian packages and 'build-essential" relate to Ruby? Is Ruby built on top of the Debian package? Put another way, does Ruby need the build-essential package to run? I really wish to see a visual representation of the relationships between all these parts.

Comment: To put it simply, if you ( or some other package you want to install ) need a C/C++ compiler, you need to install build-essential. Usually it's the first thing I install in a new Ubuntu installation :-)

Comment: @Adam Since Ruby is an interpreted language, the interpreter needs the C or C++ compiler to build itself to run on your machine. `build-essential` is a metapackage (a package that installs many other packages, like g++ and gcc: the GNU C & C++ compilers). It's required if you want to compile anything from source, and if you want to work with almost any programming language. HTH!

Comment: This answer is wrong.  The answer below is the correct one. `build-dep` is an apt-get command and `build-essential` is a package.

Comment: This is not the correct answer. The link provided gives no insight or explanation as to what is in the build-essential package.

Comment: Cross: *[Errors while compiling with CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31421327/errors-while-compiling-with-cmake/43008465#43008465)*

Answer (score 78):

The command `sudo apt-get build-dep packagename` means "As root, install all dependencies for 'packagename' so that I can build it". So build-dep is an apt-get command just like install, remove, update, etc.

`build-essential` is a package which contains references to numerous packages needed for building software in general.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the 'build-dep' command. So as I understand it, in this case Ruby1.9 has a dependency list attached to it that Linux looks to as a 'To Do/Build List' and one by one builds each of those items. The final infrastructure that gets built allows Ruby1.9 to function properly. 

What I do not understand is why 'build-essential' ,or all of the other packages in the top line( zlib1g zlib1g-dev zlibc libruby1.9 etc. etc.), would not be included in the 'To Do/Build List' attached to Ruby1.9. Wouldn't it be simpler if there was just one command?

Answer (score 12):

`build-essential` has one magical property: it does not need to be listed as a build dependency under the `Build-Depends` control field (`debian-packages`) of source packages as documented at https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-source.html#s-pkg-relations

You can get a list of the build-essential packages at:

```
cat /usr/share/doc/build-essential/list
```

You can also determine if a package is part of `build-essential` with:

```
apt-cache show gcc
```

which says:

```
Build-Essential: yes
```

Comment: +1 for pointing out where the list can be found.  The `build-essential` package description states that "This package contains an informational list of packages which are considered essential for building Debian packages," but does not mention where that list is.  I found `/usr/share/doc/build-essential/list` among the output of `apt-file show build-essential`, but is there a better way to get this information (like a help file or man page for the package)?

Comment: @user001 I don't know. `apt-file show` is almost as good as `man` for me these days XD

Comment: @user001 It's mentioned in the Debian Policy Manual, the section cited/linked in this answer.

Answer (score 6):

"build-essential" contains tools (like the gcc compiler, make tool, etc) for compiling/building software from source. So you start with (usually C) source files and create executables from them.

If you are just trying to get Ruby installed, I would highly recommend just using [RVM (Ruby Version Manager)](https://rvm.io/rvm/install/):

Follow the instructions under "Github Repository (recommended)"

Note that you will need the Git version control software installed first. Use `apt-get install git-core` if you don't have that yet.