# Weird file not found in WSL

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I can open files with `Vim`, but i can't compile them with `cc` every time it says:

`cc: error trying to exec 'cc1plus': execvp: No such file or directory`

files are also listed in `ll`

Comment: A partial explanation is that the C compiler comes in many pieces; `cc1plus` is one of those pieces.  For some reason, you had the `cc` piece (if you hadn’t had it, you would have gotten `cc: command not found`) but you didn’t have the `cc1plus` piece.  So `cc` got that error when you ran it.  And the commands Keltari gave you should install the entire C compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get install --reinstall build-essential

Comment: That worked, i would appreciate further explanations tho

Comment: @MohammadLord https://superuser.com/questions/151557/what-are-build-essential-build-dep