# Installing a math software on Oracle Virtualbox

Tags: windows-7, linux, virtualbox, installation, packages

I am new to the Oracle Virtualbox world and linux. I am currently in need to install the software here https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~latte/software.php in Oracle Virtualbox running linux and I use windows 7 professional. https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~latte/software/packages/latte_current/latte-integrale-1.7.3b.tar.gz contains the software I need as per page 31 of the manual https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~latte/software/packages/latte_current/manual_v1.7.2.pdf and I have unzipped it. I do not know how to go about installing it. It has no RPM or DEB files which are the linux packages as per http://www.control-escape.com/linux/lx-swinstall.html. What exactly should I do in this particular case and could someone provide linux tips?

Answer (score 1):

It is telling you to *compile* the application, rather than install a prebuilt application.As such there's no RPM or Deb. Each of those commands walks you though configuring, (./config), compiling (make) and performing some post compilation tasks (make install).

You'd want to install a compiler and support libraries - on ubuntu, this would be called there's a meta-package called build-essential you can install with apt, and that should let you compile c and c++ libraries. Typically at the configuration stage, there's a few useful warnings about things that you might want (WARNING) or need (ERROR). Typically these will suggest necessary development packages - you can often just search for these names, install a package ending in -dev or -devel, and run configure again until you have a number of warnings for things you're sure you don't need. Rinse and repeat for each library and the software itself.

After that just follow the instructions. Apparently the latte integrale package contains all the libraries you need, patched so its unlikely you'll need to grab development packages.

Comment: So I just do './configure --prefix=$HOME/latte --with-default=$HOME/latte' followed by 'make' and 'make install' (this is what is in the end)?

Comment: How to install a compiler and support libraries? Is there an easy way?

Comment: Its covered in my answer - install build-essential or its equivalent. The exact package depends on your distro - https://superuser.com/questions/151557/what-are-build-essential-build-dep is worth a look. The package will differ based on your distribution.

Comment: Its worth understanding what each of those commands do, rather than running them blindly. That specific invocation of the configure script for example, sets a few essential defaults for your build.

Comment: Let me take a look at the other answer.